# Macro code to copy a cell and paste it to the next 2 cells

Tags: vba, excel

Trying a write a macro to copy a cell and paste it to the next three cells.Then copying the fifth cell and paste it to the 6th, 7th and 8th cell in the row.I have a lot of data in the row that need to be copy-pasted in this way. I have something like this so far.

```
    Sub copycell()
    for i= 1 to 1000

    Cells(1, i).Select
    Selection.copy
    Cells(1,i+1).Select 
    Selection.Paste      
    end if 
    End sub   
    next i
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
Sub copycell()
    For i = 1 To 1000 Step 4
        Cells(1, i).Copy
        Range(Cells(1, i + 1), Cells(1, i + 3)).PasteSpecial
    Next i
End Sub
```

or simply

```
Sub copycell()
    For i = 1 To 100 Step 4
        Range(Cells(1, i + 1), Cells(1, i + 3)).Value = Cells(1, i).Value
    Next i
End Sub
```

`Step` keyword is used to specify a different increment for the counter variable of a loop. `Step` changes the value used to increment the counter. In this case, `i` will increment by 4 i.e. from `1 to 5` then to `9` then to `13` and so on...

Above code will copy cells in a row across to the right.
If you want to copy cells down in a column then you can use following code.

```
Sub copycell()
    For i = 1 To 100 Step 4
        Range(Cells(i + 1, 1), Cells(i + 3, 1)) = Cells(i, 1)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is, 4 steps between each loop in order to  move to the fifth cell from the first cell.

```
Sub copycell()
for i= 1 to 1000 step 4
Cells(1,i+1) = Cells(1, i)
Cells(1,i+2) = Cells(1, i) 
Cells(1,i+3) = Cells(1, i)      
next i
End sub
```